# Upload file to server with Dart

Tags: file-upload, dart

I am using something like this for my tests:

```dart
_sendFormData(final File file) {
    final HttpRequest httprequest = new HttpRequest();
    final String filename = file.name;

    httprequest.open('POST', "http://localhost:8080/api/file/upload");
    httprequest.on.readyStateChange.add((e) {
      if (httprequest.readyState == 4 && httprequest.status == 200) {
        window.alert("upload complete");
      }
    });

    print("Filename: ${filename}");

    final FormData formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', null, filename);
    httprequest.send(formData);
}
```

And yes I know it's only the filename that I am sending, but how can I send the whole file to the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to upload `file` with :

```dart
formData.append('file', file);
```

Comment: I downloaded the latest continuous build, copied the Chromium Version 25.0.1364.0 (173683) into my dart-folder (Editor 16323) and guess what - it works. 

(with formData.append('file', file, file.name);) :-))

Comment: Hmmm, drives me crazy. I switched back to Chromium Version 25.0.1324.0 (167142). This is the one which comes with M2 16323. Deleted the browser-profile because it showed an error and now... Everything is fine. My sample App works!

But now I am not sure if something got mixed up in a positive way or if the solution is simply to add both params file AND filename: formData.append('file', file, file.name);

Comment: With Dartium *25.0.1324.0 (167142)* the request content is the same if I put `file.name` or `null` as `filename`. I will test with the next integration build once available.

Comment: After more tests, it seems to work in Dartium *25.0.1324.0 (167142)*. I received file content on server as expected.

Answer (score 4):

They introduced a new function to append files with a given fileName:

```
FormData.appendBlob(String name, Blob value, [String filename])
```